# Como alinear dos divs en bootstrap horizontalmente

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Soy novato con boostrap y quiero alinear dos divs que estan dentro de un div con class "row"
estoy intentando lograr que los botones esten en vertical a la izquierda de mi tabla y el button agregar se quede ahi abajo.

Estoy usando un contenedor para los botones y otro contenedor para la tabla y un contenedor principal donde estan esos dos divs para poder alinearlos como explico pero no logro hacerlo, si me ayudan seria genial, muchas gracias!

Y si no está de más si me pudieran ayudar tambien para saber como hacer lo que explico de una manera responsive jeje
Edit: Me olvide de agregar el button jaja

aqui el codigo:

```css
.main-container {
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.container-table {
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main-container mb-5">


        <fieldset class="border p-2 col-10">

            <legend class="w-auto"><strong>Gestión de rutinas</strong> </legend>

            <div class="row mt-5 align-items-center justify-content-center">


                <div class="buttons mb-2 mt-2 p-1 btn-group-vertical">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary w-25 mr-2">Comunicaciones</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary w-25 mr-2">Radio ayudas</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary w-25 mr-2">Electromecanica</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary w-25 mr-2">Radar</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary w-25">Procesamiento de datos</button>

                </div>


                <div class="container-table col-sm-10">


                    <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                                <th scope="col">Equipo</th>
                                <th scope="col">Rutina</th>
                                <th scope="col">Periodo</th>
                                <th scope="col">Tiempo</th>
                                <th scope="col">Ver Procedimientos</th>
                                <th scope="col">Modificar</th>
                                <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">001</th>
                                <td>Telefono</td>
                                <td>1.0 Limpieza y revisión</td>
                                <td>Mensual</td>
                                <td>30 min</td>
                                <td><a href="">VER</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" style="color: black;"><strong><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></strong></a>
                                </td>
                                <td><a href="#" style="color: black;"><strong><i
                                                class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></strong></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">002</th>
                                <td>Impresora</td>
                                <td>2.0 Revisión</td>
                                <td>Semanal</td>
                                <td>1 hr</td>
                                <td><a href="">VER</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" style="color: black;"><strong><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></strong></a>
                                </td>
                                <td><a href="#" style="color: black;"><strong><i
                                                class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></strong></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">003</th>
                                <td>Computadora</td>
                                <td>3.0 Formateo y limpieza</td>
                                <td>Mensual</td>
                                <td>1hr min</td>
                                <td><a href="">VER</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" style="color: black;"><strong><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></strong></a>
                                </td>
                                <td><a href="#" style="color: black;"><strong><i
                                                class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></strong></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>


                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button modal -->

            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5 mb-5 float-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Agregar rutina
            </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo con ese código los botones quedan a la izquierda y la tabla a la derecha, pero a los botones le has puesto class w-25, por lo que están recortados y no se ven completos. Quítale el w-25 y se verán completos a la izquierda.
En lo de responsive pues depende que buscas, porque la table en un móvil se va a ver regular por el tamaño.

Comment: Es que soy tonto no se como se me pudo pasar, muchas gracias por la respuesta de verdad